# Relationship between functional derivative and potential value at a position

Tags: density-functional-theory, mathematical-modeling, kohn-sham

Thanks to very helpful and detailed answers for [my previous question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/functional-derivative-of-energy-with-respect-to-density),
I understand the functional derivative of the energy with respect to the density.
In addition, this functional derivative is equal to zero as follows (this screenshot is a page of the paper: "[A bird's-eye view of density-functional theory [PDF]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0211443.pdf)").

[image]

Here, this equation means that
the sum of the potential terms (external $v_\text{ext}$, Hartree $v_\text{H}$,
and exchange-correlation $v_\text{xc}$ (e.g., LDA))
and the functional derivative of the kinetic energy with respect to the density,
$δT_s[n]/δn(r)$, is zero.
In other words, does this mean that
we have **zero at all positions** as shown in the following figure? Is it right?

[image]

Here, the $δT_s[n]/δn(r)$ term remains in the equation. Is it possible to write this term with **a clear expression** like these potential terms? More precisely, the kinetic energy is a functional of $\psi$ in the Kohn-Sham DFT (i.e., $T_s[\{\psi_i(r)\}_{i=1}^N]$, where $\psi$ is the Kohn-Sham orbital), but can't we write down this derivative using another equation without $δ$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the sum of these potentials is zero everywhere with the true ground-state density. But the true ground-state density is generally only expressible when the basis set is complete (if you know the true ground-state density in advance, you can of course construct a finite basis set that reproduces it exactly, but if you don't know the exact density, you normally have to use a complete basis set). So in an actual calculation, the sum of the potentials will in general not be everywhere zero, especially far away from the molecule and/or near the nuclei, where the quality of the basis set is generally poor.

As for the functional derivative of the kinetic energy - of course you may write it as something like $v_{T_s}(\mathbf{r})$ (I'm not sure about what the most common notation in the literature is, though). The literature you cited spelled out the functional derivative explicitly, because in the Kohn-Sham approach the real-space representation of this functional derivative never appears in the actual calculations - it is transformed away after introducing the Kohn-Sham orbitals. In orbital-free DFT, however, one may be more willing to write this term in a form similar to $v_{T_s}(\mathbf{r})$, because in this case the latter form is indeed involved directly in the calculations.

Comment: Its an interesting discussion, but since its already gone on a few comments and is somewhat tangential to the main post, I moved it to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59055575#59055575)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The functional derivative of kinetic energy and orbital-free DFT are also interesting topic and I will try to study!

Answer (score 3):

Since we are considering the left side of your Eq. 69 as a function of $\mathbf{r}$, it must be the constant function of $\mathbf{r}$ that is 0 everywhere: $0(\mathbf{r})$. If it were any other function, such that the left side of the equation were to be non-zero anywhere, we would not write a 0 there. So it's true that your Eq. 69 is saying that the RHS is zero at all of the points in your diagram.

As [wzkchem5 said](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6663/5), Eq. 69 will not in practice be true in your real-world computer calculations, and is likely to be further away from 0 at places where the basis set is not as good of an approximation of the true function its aiming to represent.

About the definition of $\frac{\delta T}{\delta n(\mathbf{r})}$: Continuing from my answer to your question "[Functional derivative of energy with respect to density](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6659/5)", this is how $T$ changes when $n(\mathbf{r})$ changes. If the change in $T$ with respect to $n(\mathbf{r})$ stays the same no matter what your position $\mathbf{r}$ is, then your functional derivative is a constant with respect to $\mathbf{r}$; let's call it $v_T$. Let's say that at each position $\mathbf{r}$, the way that $T$ changes with respect to $n(\mathbf{r})$ is slightly different, then the functional derivative will have some $r$ dependence, so we can call it $v_T(\mathbf{r})$. As wzkchem5 said, this may make sense in [orbital-free DFT](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=orbital+free+dft), but in Kohn-Sham DFT the introduction of the KS orbitals replaces the need for dealing directly with any such $v_T(\mathbf{r})$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found some recent studies that consider the functional derivative of the kinetic energy with machine learning, and I will also try to study them.  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00580